# Vite HMR is not functioning as expected when utilizing npm package. However, when using code from package in application HMR operates successfully

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, bundler

HMR updates are not taking effect on the frontend, even though the modified module is loaded and visible in the network tab. I've developed an npm package called "ui-extension," installed it in my Vite project using "yalc," but HMR doesn't apply the changes made to the Testing.vue component or other files. Strangely, when I integrate the same code directly into my project, HMR functions as expected. Why does HMR fail to work when using an npm package?

```
// import { initializeApp } from "../library"//HMR works when i use it within my project;
import { initializeApp } from "ui-extension" // HMR does not work when i use it with npm package;
import Testing from './Testing.vue' initializeApp({ testing: Testing, })
```

Tried optimizedeps option with force etc

Comment: You're right. However, I'm not interested in monitoring changes to npm package. My focus is on monitoring any modifications that take place within the components I've provided to the library I've created. As demonstrated in the code provided in the previous question, I'm handing over the 'Testing' component to the library. The objective is that whenever any alterations happen in the 'Testing.vue' file, those changes should be reflected through HMR. but, this doesn't appear to be occurring.

Comment: yes library is within node_modules.
I conducted a test project to investigate whether the issue lies within my custom library or extends to the creation of npm packages. In this experiment, I developed an npm package named "temp-library" and subsequently published it. The purpose of this test was to eliminate any potential concerns regarding the usage of "npm link." Within this library, I encapsulated a Vue method, specifically createApp, and integrated it into my application. "please continue reading in below comment"

Comment: Surprisingly, the Hot Module Replacement (HMR) functionality encountered issues when utilized from my custom library. However, upon directly employing the createApp method from Vue itself, the HMR functionality operated as expected. This led me to question whether specific steps must be taken during the development of a library to enable proper HMR functionality. It's worth noting that even when I employed Vue's createApp method directly from the npm package, HMR worked flawlessly, despite Vue itself being an npm package. "please continue reading in below comment for code understanding"

Comment: `import { AppC } from 'temp-library'
import App from './App.vue'

const createdApp = AppC(App)
createdApp.mount('#app')
//HMR not working when used my custom library in which AppC definition is as
import { createApp } from 'vue'
export const AppC = (Testing) => {
    return createApp(Testing)
    } 
// HMR works when i use vue directly
import App from './App.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const createdApp =createApp(App)
createdApp.mount('#app')`